# How to make a 2D adjustable model with sliders?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile, flutter-animation

I am building an app in flutter where I need to make a 2D model that the user is able to transform using some sliders.

I have been breaking my head trying to figure out the options.

The idea is that there is a 2D object that has different sections, for example, a mushroom would have a base, lower shaft, upper shaft, head base, head, etc.

The user should be able to modify the total length of the mushroom, the width of each individual section, as well as the curvature of the mushroom (the user selects a point in the mushroom and the curvature should begin from that point), all by using sliders.

I would be really grateful if someone can point me on how to achieve this.

Thank you!

So far considered a CustomPaint widget but the mushroom image looks ugly and very basic.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I don’t even have code to share, I’m still stuck in picturing the design.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look into `Transform` widget, especially the `Transform.scale` constructor, for some easy 2D transformation manipulation.

Using the example you provided in your question, you can separate different "parts" of the mushroom into different `Image` widgets, each with its own `Transform` widget, and `Stack` all of them together for a whole view.

Answer (score 0):

So to answer my own question: Rive is hands down exactly what I was looking for. https://rive.app/ its basically an editing tool to create interactive animations.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34507757)